# Will Azure BizSpark charges be paid automatically

Tags: azure, bizspark

Lets say we are using BizSpark in Azure with 130EUR starting credits, and consumption comes out to be 200EUR. I'll be charged to pay 70EUR. Will these charges be paid automatically if I've entered the credit card info to my subscription?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer is yes. Your credit card will be charged automatically for the excess charges (70 EUR in your example) approximately within a month after your billing cycle ends.